# Samsung Galaxy s4 in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, adt, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I want to test my App in a Samsung Galaxy S4, i've checked "unknown sources" and enabled the developer menu and checked "Debug mode". But It is displayed offline

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb.exe devices
List of devices attached
XXXXXXXX        offline
```

any ideas why?

Comment: Try deattaching your phone and rebooting it.  Offline is generally a problem in USB connectivity or the phone getting into an odd state.

Comment: tried that, but no effort =(

Comment: do i need any other setting or driver? my galaxy s1 works well. Maybe another USB-Mode? i can choose MTP and PTP

Comment: If it sees the phone as offline (rather than not seeing it at all), then it isn't a driver issue.

Comment: Please note that you don't need to allow "unknown sources" to install apps with adb (same for Eclipse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you have latest Android SDK tools. 
After installing latest SDK tools, check your phone: you need to confirm that you allow debugging from your computer.

Comment: the out-dated SDK tools where the problem

Answer (score 3):

For me, it wasn't until I updated my computer's drivers with Samsung's official driver that I could get my S4 to be recognized in Eclipse (also, don't forget to enable Debugging mode)

The driver url: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-I747MBBATT

Comment: This solution works on new ADT installs (no Android SDK tools update required)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran my first app - hel,lo world - on my Galaxy s4 Active.

I developed it yesterday and it would run on the emulator but even though my phone was connected to the computer through USB and I could transfer files and also kies air worked Eclipse could not see the phone.

Today I downloaded and installed the latest driver from Samsung for the Galaxy s4 Active, SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.23.0-retail, on the computer.  I opened the app in Eclipse and hit RUN and and the phone was now visible.  I chose the phone and the app transferred to the phone and would run on the phone.

As noted, the phone was visible to the computer and apparently was working in every way, except development, before I downloaded and installed the new driver.  I've only had my phone about a month so I'm not sure why the original driver would not "develop".

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behaviour is device is unauthorised  for USB debugging. Ideally a pop up should appear on the device asking to provide permission for USB debugging. Select Allow always for this computer and click OK. This will solve the offline issue.

If the pop up does not come up when you plug the device to computer. Open adb command prompt and run

**adb usb** in command prompt(with device connected to computer through USB) this will reboot android adb usb listner which will force the pop up to come on the device.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is:**

**1st** Make sure that your device is not connected in your computer 
**2nd** Disable USB Debugging mode in your phone 
**3rd** Connect your device with USB cable to your computer 
**4th** enable usb debugging mode (should have already pressed the "about" phone 7 times) 
**5th** Message Dialog about fingerprint of your computer will be displayed, just press ok 
Prerequisites:
 -installed complete adt environment with downloaded sdks, 
-installed samsung usb driver

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 for Samsung Galaxy S4 the only thing that helped me was to install **KIES 3** and to use **Tools->Reinstall device driver**. I tried to install only usb driver given as link here http://www.teamandroid.com/download-android-usb-drivers/ but it was not enough.

My current working driver version is 2.9.319.511. Android version is 4.4.2. Now I see the device in Android Developer Tools, KIES 3 and adb devices.

Additional notes: I found several links on Samsung site for download of different versions of the device driver - it seems they don't keep all links up to date. I also had another issue - I downloaded KIES 3, installed it and on start of the application I immediately received a popup that an update is available and if I want to update KIES 3 I have to uninstall the current installation. So I also chose to uninstall KIES 3 and install the last update. Only then I reinstalled the device driver.