# Phone not being recognised by Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 that I would like to deploy my app to using eclipse. However the device simply does not appear on the list of devices to deploy to.

- I am using Windows 7 64-bit.
- The phone appears as a drive when plugged in, allowing me to transfer files to and from the device.
- The phone has *developer mode* and *USB debugging* switched on.
- In the Android SDK Manager, the `Google USB Driver` appears as *installed*.
- I have manually installed the usb driver located at `\extras\google\usb_driver\`.
- This same device has been recognised and deployed to on other computers.
- I have tried restarting the adb server in command prompt using `adb kill-server` and then typing `adb start-server`.
- I have tried restarting both the phone and the computer.

My deployment screen simply thinks there is no android device:

[image]

Any ideas? Is there perhaps something I am missing here that is required for my android device to be properly recognised by eclipse?

Comment: Usb Debugging should be ON.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Please read the question, usb debugging is on

Comment: @SherifelKhatib : `The phone has developer mode and USB debugging switched on.`

Comment: Yes sorry mmm. Try changing USB mode to PTP.

Comment: could be the version of adt or of the sdk tools you are using : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799929/samsung-galaxy-s4-in-eclipse-adt

Comment: what does "adb devices" return you?

Comment: A device ID and the status `Unauthorized`... I assume this is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, is your device id showing up when you use `adb devices`

If it is, it's just a matter of restarting eclipse.  Another cause could be that you're using the Google USB driver, whereas you should be using Samsung's Android USB driver, which can be found here:

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Comment: I have downloaded and installed this driver - and now I try `adb devices` in command prompt and one device is listed (I assume it is my phone), but it says `Unauthorized`. I'm guessing this is problem? How do I authorize it?

Comment: Look on your phone, it should ask if you trust your computer's RSA Fingerprint.  Press "OK" and try adb devices again, it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Get the drivers for your Galaxy S4 here:
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows
P.S. ya better got Nexus 5

Answer (score 0):

You should install Samsung KIES, that have included some USB Drivers and something more, then you will able the possibility to eclipse sdk recognize your Phone, i was with the same problem, after i installed KIES everything worked fine, trust me.

KIES Download:
http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/